# Wavy box in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there a way to make a box with a wavy top with Canvas?

I would like to know if this effect can be achieved directly with a Canvas, it is not necessary to have a scrolling animation.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not quite clear why you're talking about `Canvas`. To crop a view like this, you can use a custom `Shape` and apply it to your view with [`Modifier.clip`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clip(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape)). Here's a shape you can use:

```
class WavyShape(
    private val period: Dp,
    private val amplitude: Dp,
) : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density,
    ) = Outline.Generic(Path().apply {
        val wavyPath = Path().apply {
            val halfPeriod = with(density) { period.toPx() } / 2
            val amplitude = with(density) { amplitude.toPx() }
            moveTo(x = -halfPeriod / 2, y = amplitude)
            repeat(ceil(size.width / halfPeriod + 1).toInt()) { i ->
                relativeQuadraticBezierTo(
                    dx1 = halfPeriod / 2,
                    dy1 = 2 * amplitude * (if (i % 2 == 0) 1 else -1),
                    dx2 = halfPeriod,
                    dy2 = 0f,
                )
            }
            lineTo(size.width, size.height)
            lineTo(0f, size.height)
        }
        val boundsPath = Path().apply {
            addRect(Rect(offset = Offset.Zero, size = size))
        }
        op(wavyPath, boundsPath, PathOperation.Intersect)
    })
}
```

If you really need to use this inside `Canvas` for some reason, you can pass the same `Path` that I create inside `WavyShape` to [`DrawScope.clipPath`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope).clipPath(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ClipOp,kotlin.Function1)), so that the contents of the `clipPath` block will be clipped.

Apply custom shape to your `Image` or any other view:

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_image_1),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(WavyShape(period = 100.dp, amplitude = 50.dp))
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What if I want to make the waves appear downside (the opposite of this)? I tried to pass a negative value for the amplitude, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Roony this is some basic geometry, try to understand what each line does and you'll be able to modify it  to your demand. or ask chatgpt, it's quite good at such kind of questions

Comment: Actually I came here after Chatgpt failed to help me. I've never worked with custom shapes before, the class doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Roony the class is just a wrapper around Path, where you add lines one by one to make a figure at the end. and path math is what chatgpt should be able to update for you- have you tried giving it my code and asking to update clipping part?