# Customize serrated shapes with Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a customized serrated shape with Jetpack Compose for an Android view, this is the example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALcFQ.png)

I don't know how to create the little waves (left/right) for this shape. Do I need to have a Box and a customized shape? Because I need to add some text inside this shape.

How can I create this element with Jetpack Compose?

Comment: You need to create a custom shape, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69720403/3585796) for an example - your waves just have to be on the other side and have different size parameters. Then you can apply it to any view with `Modifier.clip`, or just pass `Surface` or `Card` as `shape` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with the method explained in Philip's answer, which will require you to create a `Shape` instance of your own. If you do not wish for it to get overcomplicated (though it is indeed fairly simple, but anyway), you could simply do this:

1.) Get the path data of the shape in a vector drawable format. If you use a prototyping software to design the layout first (like Figma, Sketch etc.), you will have access to plugins, third-party or first, that should allow you to extract the pathdata from the shape of your choosing. For Figma, for instance, there's the 'Android Vector Drawable' plugin, that extracts the complete android-vector-drawable format code for the shape. If you do not use a service like this, just look up on the web and get the data from an online path extractor. They are basically SVG paths, with a slightly different approach. Anyway, all you need for this step is the path-data of the shape (It is a simple enough shape, you could even draw the vector yourself using some good-ol' trigonometry)

2.) Once, you have the path data, it is easy. Just create a Vector Drawable and draw the shape on screen like so

```
Image(
 painter = rememberPainterResource(id = R.drawable.shape) // Id refers to your drawable
)
```

You can use it inside a Box with a `Text` and you'll achieve that.

Other than that, you could use path-data directly in a `Canvas` so you do not need to create a Drawable Resource explicitly.

```
Canvas {
 drawPath(
  PathParser.createPathFromPathData(yourDataHere).asComposePath()
 )
}
```

There you have it.

Comment: Please mark the above as the correct answer so as to inform others that the query has been resolved. It's a small tick icon under the votes counter to the left of the answer.